# if else function is not working properly in php

Tags: php

I have a html page that asks the user to enter an email address and then when the user clicks on submit he gets redirected to a link using a php file that I made, but for some reason the php file is not working, it always redirects to the else link my php and my html are below.

```html
<form action="/emailprocess.php">
  Email Address:<br>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  <input id="emailaddress" type="submit" class="emailaddress" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```
<?php

If($_POST['email'] === "me@apple.com") {
    header("Location: https://www.google.co.uk/");

    } else {
        header("Location: https://google.com/");
    }
?>
```

Comment: this is more of a typo question. just add `method='post'` to your `<form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set method to `post` in html code and use `if` instead of `IF`,also better to use `==` instead of `===`(since the later will also check the type)

HTML code:

```
<form action="/emailprocess.php" method="post">
  Email Address:<br>
  <input id="email" type="text" name="email">
  <br><br>
  <input id="emailaddress" type="submit" class="emailaddress" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['email'] == "me@apple.com") {
   header("Location: https://www.google.co.uk/");
} else {
   header("Location: https://google.com/");
}
?>
```

Comment: works, thanks alot

Comment: sure, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Set method=post in your HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<form action="/emailprocess.php">
```

with

```
<form action="/emailprocess.php" method="post">
```

default method attribute is get when you do no insert method attribute in form

so when you submit form  this condition if($_POST['email'] == "me@apple.com") never execute